# Async update in MVVM and animation on state change

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mvvm, combine

I trying to understand how Combine and SwiftUI works in combination with MVVM and clean architecture, but I encountered a problem with using `withAnimation` once my view model has an async method that updated published value. I was able to solve it, but I'm pretty sure it's not the correct way and I'm missing something fundamental. Here it is how it looks my solution, starting with my data manager:

```swift
protocol NameManaging {
    var publisher: AnyPublisher<[Name], Never> { get }
    func fetchNames() async
}

class MockNameManager: NameManaging {
    var publisher: AnyPublisher<[Name], Never> {
        names.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func fetchNames() async {
        var values =  await heavyAsyncTask()
        names.value.append(contentsOf: values)
    }

    private func heavyAsyncTask() async -> [Name] {
        // do some heavy async task
    }

    private var names = CurrentValueSubject<[Name], Never>([])
}
```

Then view models:

```swift
class NameListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var names = [Name]()
    private var anyCancellable: AnyCancellable?
    private var nameManager: NameManaging

    init(nameManager: NameManaging = MockNameManager()) {
        self.nameManager = nameManager
        self.anyCancellable = nameManager.publisher
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] values in
                withAnimation {
                    self?.names = values
                }
            })
    }

    func fetchNames() async {
        await nameManager.fetchNames()
    }
}
```

Lastly my view:

```swift
struct NameList: View {
    @StateObject private var nameListViewModel = NameListViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: updateNames) {
                        Text("Fetch some more names")
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()

            List {
                ForEach(nameListViewModel.names) {
                    NameRow(name: $0)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Names list")
        .onAppear(perform: updateNames)
    }

    func updateNames() {
        Task {
            await nameListViewModel.fetchNames()
        }
    }
}
```

What I did is use `withAnimation` inside my view model in `.sink()` method of data manager publisher. This works as expected, but it indroduce view function inside view model. How can I do it in a way that inside `updateNames` in my view I'll use `withAnimation`? Or maybe I should do it in completely different way?

Comment: This isn’t MVVM view models should never know anything about each other. Also the whole publisher setup is unnesessary you can just return the array or use AsyncStream

Comment: @lorem-ipsum in this case yes, publisher is unnecessary, but my point is to learn combine and in the future behind data manager might be something that has real async job to do. Regarding MVVM - in that case should I return just model and then in view create view model for row?

Comment: That depends on several things it could be just the identifier but it all depends on the app and the next steps. But architecture application is very subjective I personally think that what you are doing is overuse and over complication, it isn’t realistic or clean. MVVM can be argued to be completely wrong for SwiftUI, I think it has selective uses. BTW an AsyncStream can easily take the place of all the publishing code, this setup is good to learn but isn’t something that belongs on a new project.

Comment: This exact example might not represent the idea well, but why do you think it's not clean? View models depends on managers so they can be easily switch for another implementation, views see only view models. Everything is separated (considering I remove dependency between view models) and easily testable. Even if MVVM is not a best choice for SwiftUI (although most of the articles/tutorials I've found seems to disagree) what isn't clean in my solution?

Comment: Not clean as in clean architecture but clean as in not a mess. Why all those computed variables in the row view model? When I’ve seen this setup it usually leads to several other layers of view models that serve no purpose. The row right now is just the tip of the issue since it isn’t actually doing anything.

Comment: Ok, note taken to not wrap simplest models into view models etc. But my point of focus here is the second view model right now. Row is just stub so I can see if everything on screen works. I'll edit the question then, so it doesn't bring unnecessary attention. Then my problem is still unresolved - how to run async methods and still get animation.

Comment: Try using the animation view modifier, with animation doesn’t belong in a view model it is specific to SwiftUI and in theory you should be able to use the same view model on SwiftUI and UIKit

Comment: Thanks! I've just quickly tried, and it looks like it works as expected!

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use the `.task` modifier to call any async func and set the result on an `@State var`. If the async func throws then you might catch the exception and set a message on another `@State var`. The great thing about `.task` is it's called when the generated UIView appears and cancelled when it disappears (also if the optional `id` param changes). It’s implemented using an internal state object so you don’t need your own anymore.

struct NameList: View {
@State var var names: [Name] = []
@State var fetchCount = 0

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button("Fetch some more names") {
                    fetchCount += 1
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()

        List {
            ForEach(names) { name in
                NameRow(name: name)
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Names list")
    .task(id: fetchCount) {
        let names = await Name.fetchNames()
        withAnimation {
            self.names = names
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: My point is to avoid using model directly inside view and move the logic to view model. Your solution mix almost everything inside view. One thing I could do is move your implementation of ```task``` to my view model and update value directly instead of through publisher from data manger, but I still wouldn't be able to use ```withAnimation``` inside view.

Comment: In SwiftUI the View struct is a view model already.

Comment: For what then there is ObservableObject protocol? Or rather why I shouldn't move the logic to separate class and keep it directly in view when it's a bit messy?

Comment: It's for model data. I recommend watching https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/